# How to run the same SAS program with data from different months in one program rather than doing it separately for each month?

Tags: sas

I need to rerun the same program with data from different months and create a separate excel spreadsheet for each month. What is a shorter way to program this in SAS than to run each program separately? For example in the following I read data from October, and at the end of the same program I output the October results to excel. I need to do the same for each month. Can I do it in one SAS program (maybe using Macro)? Thanks.

```
data sourceh.trades2;
set sourceh.trades1_october08_wk1;
if time<34200000 or time>57602000 then delete;
run;

proc export data=sourceh.avesymbol        
outfile='C:\Documents and Settings\zd\My Documents\h\hdata\trades\2008\October 08 1 min       correlations.xls'           
replace; 
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a macro for that. Here I have wrapped your code into a macro which you can execute with the `RunProgram();` macro statement for each desired month and year.

```
%MACRO RunProgram(month, year);
data sourceh.trades2;
set sourceh.trades1_&month.&year._wk1;
if time<34200000 or time>57602000 then delete;
run;

proc export data=sourceh.avesymbol        
outfile="C:\Documents and Settings\zd\My Documents\h\hdata\trades\2008\&month. &year. 1 min correlations.xls"         
replace; 
run;
%MEND RunProgram;


%RunProgram(October, 08);
%RunProgram(November, 08);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I updated the program but it doesn't understand the macro in the proc export. Instead of creating two excel files that start with October08 and November08 the program creates an excel file called '&month. &year. 1 min correlations.xls'. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yeah - sorry about that. I forgot that file directories need to be inside double quote marks (") instead of single quote marks (') if they contain macro variables. I have edited the code.